# Check the variable value inside inline function

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I am trying to debug the code that uses inline function. The code is written in C++ and compiled with MSVC 2010.

My question is - how do I check the value of the variable inside inline function? Here is the code sample:

```
class A
{
public:
    void *GetMember() { return m_data; }
private:
    void *m_data;
};
```

Hovering over the m_data does not show the tooltip and the variable is not shown in any of the "Debug->Watch..."

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the program in `debug` mode?

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi, yes, I'm positive. I start the program by pressing "F5".

Comment: Below the menus, there is a combo box, see if `debug` is selected. I'm pretty sure you are on `release` mode. It's not about inline functions. I've been working with VS for many year now.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: untested suggestion:

Change the function to a multi-line implementation

```
void *GetMember()
{
   return m_data;
}
```

Set a break point at the `return` line.

When the program breaks at the line, hovering over `m_data` should show its value.

Comment: unfortunately this code is in the 3rd party library which I prefer to not to recompile. Hence the question. Any other idea? If there is none, I will recompile, of course. Thx.